# I want to have my side columns disappear when the screen isn't wide enough (Without JS)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my webpage responsive so that whenever the screen is less than 600 px wide, I want the side columns to completely disappear, not just form on top of each other. I've messed around with changing ratios to 0% and that didn't work. If possible I'd like to be able to do this using only HTML and CSS, because I have no experience with Java. If there is no way to do it without Java, please let me know so I can find a java basics tutorial somewhere.

```
  <DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
      <title>Title</title>
      <style>
        .topnav {
          overflow: hidden;
          background-color: black;
          display:flex;
        }

        .topnav a {
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        .topnav a:first-child {
          font-weight: 700;
        }
        .topnav a:hover {
          background-color: #151515;
          font-weight: 700;
        }
        .topnav a:before {
          display: block;
          content: attr(data-title);
          font-weight: 700;
          overflow: hidden;
          visibility: hidden;
          height: 0;
        }
        .footer {
          background-color: black;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 10px;
          margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        .center {
          text-align: center;
        }
        .column {
          float: left;
          padding: 10px;
        }
        .column.side {
          width: 25%;
        }
        .column.middle {
          width: 50%;
        }
        .row:after {
          content: "";
          display: table;
          clear: both;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
          .column.side, .column.middle {
            width: 100%;
          }
        }
        body {
          height: 100%;
        }
        .page-wrap {
          min-height: 100%;
          margin-bottom: -142px;
        }
        .page-wrap:after {
          content: "";
          display: block;
        }
        .footer, .page-wrape:after {
          height: 142px;
        }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page-wrap">
      <h>heading<h>
      <div class="topnav">
        <a data-title="Home" href="\index.html">Home</a>
        <a data-title="Page 2" href="\Page2\index.html">Coming Soon</a>
        <a data-title="Page 3" href="\Page3\index.html">Video Library</a>
        <a data-title="Page 4" href="\Page4\index.html">Cast and Crew</a>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column side">
          <p>I want this to disappear</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column middle">
          <p>I want this to stay</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column side">
          <p>I want this to disappear</div>
        </div>
    </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <p>Footer contents</p>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `display: none` the `.column.side` divs in your media query:

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .column.side {
        display: none;
      }
    }
```